# build boost with both 32bit and 64bit with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, 32bit-64bit

I have configured boost to build both 32bit and 64bit libraries with versioned layout.

However it did not include address model in the file name layout, so the 32bit and 64bit libraries have the same filename and therefore can't share the lib directory.

What is the recommended way to have both 32bit and 64bit boost libraries ?

Comment: isn't boost header only?

Comment: Its mostly headers, but not entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was by specifying --libdir on the b2 command line and have it point to a different directory. I called it "libx64" and made the layout look like this:

include -> With boost underneath it, standard boost layout
  lib -> Standard boost lib dir, use that for the 32 bit libraries
  libx64 -> 64 bit libraries only

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking similarly but was surprised that there appeared to be no standard for it.